# Ts destructuring array of string to be a parameters

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-2016

Hi I have an array of keys

Ex1:

```
const arrWithKeys = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to use them as parameters because I don't want to write them multiple times, there is a way to achieve it?.

Ex2:

```
const [...arrWithKeys] = someFunc(arrWithKeys)
```

and then I can use it as a parameters

```
const title = a.title
```

- Ex2 doesn't work

Comment: You want to use `someFunc` to retrieve the values corresponding to the given set of keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket parameter syntax while looping over the array like

```
const result: {[key: string]: any} = someFunc(arrWithKeys)
for (key of arrWithKeys) { // or (key in result)
  doSomethingWith(result[key])
}
```

Declaring a variable set of local variables based on the array's contents is probably not a great idea. It's better to keep `someFunc`'s results in some object.